# How to find out lower opacity color?

Tags: color, transparency, hex

Is there any way to find a similar color code when reducing the opacity of any color?
For example:

[image]

Comment: I'd just hover my colour meter over it - though I'd be far more concerned how you arrived at 0xf5f5f5 … which is actually almost white. I see 0x5d5d5d & the 10% as 0xdfdfdf

Comment: @Tetsujin It does not work when you work with white color share, for eg. if you are taking 60% of white using color meter/ eye dropper it shows a shade of gray, maybe (f8f8f8) which is not correct I guess?

Comment: "white color share" - what's that? Are you working in cmyk+spot white? In RGB, 40% black over a white background is the same colour as 60% transparent white over black.

Comment: @Tetsujin White color 'Shade' sorry for typo :P. Basically I want a lite white shade (approx 60%) on a blue background, but when I am reducing the opacity and taking that color using eyedropper, it changes to gray.

Comment: Your issue seems to keep changing with each iteration, I'm struggling to keep up with what you actually need. There was no mention of blue in your question, just some grey text with incorrect colour numbers. All I can suggest it set the eye-dropper to 'all layers'. btw, I didn't mean eye dropper; I have an independent tool which simply measures the colour at any point on the screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am sorry if I could not explain it properly. I have added another image for your reference maybe now you'd understand what I am asking :)

Comment: OPen thepicture in a editor and use eyedropper tool.

Comment: From a picture, I'd still hover my colour meter over it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov0RI.jpg - in Photoshop I'd use the eye-droppper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a colour picker tool.  If you are using graphics software such as Photoshop or GIMP, use the colour picker included.  If your image has layers, you may have to change the settings to "sample merged".

If you don't have software like that, there are several tools that you can get that have a colour picker.  One that I use is ShareX*, which is free screen capture software, for Windows. It has a *Screen color picker* tool included.

[image]

***Note**: I have no affiliation with ShareX. There are many other similar tools available.

Comment: Thanks, Billy, for the app recommendation. This is built-in on Mac so I had no clue what Win may need. [I'm glad we agree on exactly what colour it is too [& mine even still agrees on *this* pic] - I haven't calibrated my screens in a month or three ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin your monitor calibration shouldn't affect the numbers as long as qe agree it is in sRGB

Comment: @joojaa - Well, I've always wondered about this & I've never been absolutely sure how it works, but I've always felt there's a double translation going on somewhere, from received, via native, back to screen profile. I have known it to be out. Post a screen shot then screenshot/post it several times, see if there's any drift.

Comment: @Tetsujin only if we disagree what the profile should be. But yeah the sytem is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: @joojaa - that's where is gets complicated ;) My image here has my monitor's profile [DELL U2713H_05-10-2021.icc which of course exists nowhere in the world except my computer]. By the time I sent it through imgur it becomes untagged RGB… I honestly lose track at that point exactly what's in charge ;) [& I just realised I haven't calibrated in the past year… that's my new task for tomorrow ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin Untagged is assumed to be sRGB, your monitor profile should only be used to make your monitor show sRGB correctly